# Migrating data from 2 different SQL Server databases using console app

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012, ef-code-first, .net-core, dbmigrate

I have 2 web applications which are let's say `Legacy1` and `New1`. I have separate `DbContext` for both applications and separate databases.

Now I want to migrate data from the `Legacy1` database to the `New1` database. I cannot simply use `copy database` or `export database` options in SQL Server. Entities are different and I need to incorporate some logic while migrating data.

I have decided to use .Net Core Console (.Net Framework) project to do this. Do I have to add both `DbContexts` to this project? Also all the entities which I want to map and do the migration or is there any other way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found a simple approach to achieve that.  I used `EF DB First` approach to generate `edmx` files for `source` and `target` databases. Which gives me access to corresponding `Entities` as well.

I Queried source database using source `dbcontext` and manipulated data as per the requirements and inserted into target database using target `dbcontext`. I used `AutoMapper` to map `source` entities to `Target` entities.

It was much simpler than i thought earlier. Hope it helps others having similar scenario.